# Vue3 + Vite => 'default' is not exported by xxx

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

Not a question but a solution so it may help others nor futur self !

I've spent 3 days trying to migrate/build a Vue3 project with Vite and having this error:

```
'default' is not exported by XXX
```

I'm importing assets dynamically as explained here:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url

```
new URL(`/src/${path}`, import.meta.url).href;
```

`path` being the path to my asset, for example "`assets/icons/xxx.svg`".

Problem is, if the new URL() base path targets the `src` folder, Vite will try to resolve the `.vue` and `.ts` files within it which generates the error above.

To solve it, just add the "assets" folder on the base path of the URL resolving, like so:

```
new URL(`/src/assets/${path}`, import.meta.url).href;
```

You're welcome futur me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't target the whole `src` folder on the URL constructor.
Set the "assets" folder so it does not try to resolve your .ts/.js/.vue files when trying to resolve dynamic assets.